# Eclipse Web-editor extremely slow when using <> brackets

Tags: eclipse, performance, jsp, editor

This is very frustrating. I'm editing GSP (or JSP) file and each time i open html brackets <> eclipse becomes extremely slow (1 sec per character).
**I searched all over the place**, disabled all validation, disabled content assist, removed auto-close tags. No effect on slowness.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

Might be because of your processor or the useless plugins activated.

I would recommend you to use [Netbeans 7.3](https://netbeans.org/downloads/). (For me)is the best IDE for Web Projects.

Netbeans has almost the same Plugins as Eclipse such HTML5 projects, Java Web and also autocomplete mode.